# Uploading images to ASP.NET MVC website and saving them in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I have a page where a client wants to upload images of kitchens and add a bit of text + a title to each. Right now my solution supports uploading images via URLs, but I want the client to be able to upload his own images from his computer onto the site via a "Browse" button.

This is my current model class:

```
public class Udstillingsmodel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string titel { get; set; }
    public string beskrivelse { get; set; }
    public string billedeSti { get; set; }
}

public class UdstillingsmodelDBContext : DbContext
{
    public UdstillingsmodelDBContext() : base("UdstillingsmodelDBContext") { }
    public DbSet<Udstillingsmodel> Udstillingsmodels { get; set; }
}
```

This is where I have the button placed currently, in the "Create" view for the model controller:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">
            <p><b>Billede:</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="image" />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.billedeSti, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.billedeSti, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

These are the two GET and POST methods for the Create function:

```
// GET: Udstillingsmodels/Create
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Udstillingsmodels/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,titel,beskrivelse,billedeSti")] Udstillingsmodel udstillingsmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Udstillingsmodels.Add(udstillingsmodel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(udstillingsmodel);
    }
```

I have the image selected via the "Browse" button named "image" as a variable, but I am unsure what to do with this and how to correctly save the image through Entity framework. Right now my "image" property for my model is merely a string, but I was thinking that it could point to a location in the contents folder, where all my other images are stored, as I've done elsewhere on the site. Let me know if you need more information and code.

This is how the "Create" view looks currently, with the button added.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxEc8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, your begin form should be like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("youraction", "Your controller", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Then Your controller's create action

```
//"image" is the name of the html fileupload element
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Udstillingsmodel udstillingsmodel,HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
 //upload image
            if (image!= null && image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
//Here, I create a custom name for uploaded image
                    string file_name = udstillingsmodel.titel + Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);

                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), file_name);
                    image.SaveAs(path);

 // image_path is nvarchar type db column. We save the name of the file in that column. 
                    udstillingsmodel.image_path= file_name;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }


        db.Udstillingsmodels.Add(udstillingsmodel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(udstillingsmodel);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure where you want me to put the first line of code. Is this supposed to replace my current code for the image upload in my "Create" view? I am not familiar with the Html.BeginForm() method.

Comment: You should have a   @using (Html.BeginForm()) code in your Create view and Edit view. Create.cshtml and Edit.cshtml.  You should replace that with which my first line of code.

Comment: Ah, now i see it, thanks. In the controller, what is the parameter needed in the method header for it to use my "image" variable from the view?

Comment: I edited my answer. If it helped, It will be very nice if you mark it as answer. you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have marked it as answered.